# How do you expose/display a product type's custom field in a product display?

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I created a custom field in my product type, but how do i get it to display on my product display when my item is selected? The field doesnt show up in managed display in the product display.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been through my settings for my product & it's display to check my settings. I have several fields added to my product which I display on product display. I have [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module enabled at my instance.

So what I have done is - I have checked *Full content* in my custom display setting tab at my product as well as product display in manage display. You can also do **Product -> Manage display -> custom display setting -> full content(check)** & save.

I have enabled all fields in my product in `full content` tab, which looks like --

[image]

After that when I visit my **product display -> manage display -> full page**, I find those field, which I have enabled to be visible. It looks like --

[image]

Comment: that's so weird.. i can't believe i missed that. thx.

Comment: @duckx - It happens :)

Comment: I have the same issue,I cannot show a custom field in a product to a product display.I am not using Display suite.How can I fix that?

Comment: Do I need Display suite to do this?

Comment: I tried that with Display suite but no luck.Is there any way to do this with code?thanks